# Separate a string around a certain character

Tags: javascript, html, string

Context: I have a text field in my form that is meant for entering an amount of money. I want variables for dollars and cents. Can javascript find the location of the decimal point, and separate it into two integers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`"$111.01".split('.');` yields `['$111', '01']`

Then it's a matter of cleaning that up (`.replace`) and coercing them into ints (`parseInt`).

Answer (score 0):

here i such Example:

http://jsfiddle.net/9FDrN/1/

HTML:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js'></script>
<input type="text" id="amount" value="$100.01">
<input type="text" id="dollars" value=""><br/>
<input type="text" id="cents" value=""><br/>
```

​

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var amount_val = $("#amount").val();
    var out = amount_val.split(".");

    $("#dollars").val(out[0].replace("$",""));
    $("#cents").val(parseInt(out[1],10));                  
    });​
```